# The "--path" option does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

The `--path` option does not exist.

```
Artisan::call("migrate --path=database/migrations/tenant")
```

I updated Laravel from 5.8 to Laravel 8.

I don't know what is wrong.

`Artisan::call("migrate")` works fine

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue in my machine. Can you make sure you have the same issue on other Laravel projects?

Comment: Author, run `php artisan migrate --help` on your terminal or CLI, check in the output if you have `--path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do put the `/` after the path, like:

`Artisan::call("migrate --path=/database/migrations/tenant");`

Comment: still not work i think something wrong happen when upgrade laravel

Comment: @mostafahamdi do all steps on [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade).